# Organize Csv file based on filestructure using JavaScript.

Tags: javascript

Here's the whole problem:
I need to create a plain csv table from a file structure from the server. 
Everyline should be organized as follows:
,

Currently, all the files on the server are organized like this:

L:\Dados\rd\20110727000002978\110614.pdf

Where the string 20110727000002978 is the docid and L:\Dados\rd\20110727000002978\110614.pdf is the file path.

So, the CSV table should have the data like this
L:\Dados\rd\20110727000002978\110614.pdf, 20110727000002978

Currently I'm using a BATCH file to do a DIR /S/B > FILELIST.TXT to list all the files, and MANUALLY updating the

Is it possible to automate this using javascript? I guess it would be a simple script, but I had no idea how to start this.

I guess I don't need to use JavaScript, as I long as I don't need any copyrighted copiler - I guess I can use anything.

As far as I know, the code itself is rather simple, but all programming I know is BATCH and a little PASCAL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you won't be able to do this entirely in JavaScript.  You'll need a sever-side language, like PHP (as an example) to do the file processing.

Comment: I gues that's not such a big problem, as I long as I don't need any copyrighted copiler - I guess I can use anything.

Comment: Yeah.. if you can accept the answer to close off the question

Comment: actually i think my question is missplaced, i'll go into more research before making adcional comments